# How can i add a Identity Role in a ASP.NET Core Webapi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-roles

i would like add roles and use this roles in my ASP.NET Core Webapi. Can someone send me a exemple code? The Name of the Role is `Admin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UserManger to get.

Like `UserManger<ApplicationUser>` where `ApplicationUser` class would be like this.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get;set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime PwdExpiryDt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool PwdExpiryFlg { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime LastPwdChgDt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ModifiedDt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Use _userManager like this

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

Add role to user like this

```
IdentityResult identityResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, applicationRole.Name);
```

In your case, you can use `RoleManger` also.

```
private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

var role = _roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == existingRole)
```

Role class would be like this.

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you can send me a example?

Comment: In what for a class must i take the RoleManager? In Startup.cs?

Comment: And he can find the existingRole in  var role = _roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == `existingRole`);

Comment: existingRole = "Admin"

Comment: What do you meant with user in `_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, applicationRole.Name);
`

Comment: You can add net role to the user

Comment: when i use the var role i become a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`